# Remove all matching chars in calc sheet with one command

Tags: replace, libreoffice

My libreoffice calc sheet uses the grave accent character ( ` ) as a prefix to numbers. I want to remove all of these characters in the simplest way possible.

**Input sheet:**

```
TABLE    Year1    Year2    Year3
Price    `0.01    `0.02    `0.03
Qty      `10      `11      `12
```

**Output sheet:**

```
TABLE    Year1    Year2    Year3
Price    0.01     0.02     0.03
Qty      10       11       12
```

Currently, I have to use search & replace for each cell to achieve this. I search for ( ` ) and replace all individual instances with a blank. This works, but is very tedious. To make matters worse, Search all and Replace all both result in overwriting the complete cell with a blank instead of just matched character.

How can I solve this issue using the options available in Libreoffice calc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go to "Edit", then "Find and Replace" then input your options (a ` and nothing) and "replace all". Make sure that you left the "Entire Cells" box unchecked.

Comment: "Entire Cells" box is unchecked which is default. but still all the matching cells are completely overwritten with blanks.

    Anyways I found the solution: In "more options" you have to uncheck the "Similarity Search" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks TLu for the help.